# complex roots of polynomial on unit circle

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

$a,b,c$ are three complex numbers such that roots of $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ lie on a unit circle
prove that roots of $Q(x)=x^3+|a|x^2+|b|x+|c|$ lie on unit circle too.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;b=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=x_1x_2x_3\left(\frac{1}{x_3}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right)=c \,\bar{a}\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$x_1 +x_2 +x_3=-a , x_1 x_2 +x_2 x_3 +x_3 x_1 =b , x_1 x_2 x_3 =-c $$
It is easy to observe that $|c| =1 $ and $$|b|^2 =1+1+1 +x_1\overline{x_2 } +x_2\overline{x_1 } +x_1\overline{x_3 }+x_3\overline{x_1 }+x_3\overline{x_2 }+x_2\overline{x_3 } =|a|^2$$
thus $$Q(x) =x^3 +|a|x^2 +|a|x +1 =(x+1)(x^2 -x +1 +|a|x )=(x+1) (x^2 -(1-|a|)x +1).$$
Denote $\Delta = (1-|a|)^2 -4 =(|a|-3)(|a|+1 )\leq 0. $ Assume that $\Delta <0$ then we have $$x_1 =\frac{1-|a| -i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2}, x_2 =\frac{1-|a| +i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2}$$
are also solutions of $Q(x) =0 $ and $$|x_1|^2 =|x_2|^2 =\frac{1-2|a|+|a|^2 -|a|^2 +2|a|+3}{4} =1$$
therefore $Q(x)$ has three roots $(-1, x_1 ,x_2 )$ on the unit circle.

If $\Delta =0 $ then $Q(x) =(x+1)^3 $ and it is also true that $Q$ has all roots on unit circle.